# Is it possible to change the map's typeface in Android Maps V2?

Tags: android, google-maps

Now that everything is nicely drawn dynamically with Google's next-gen Maps library I wonder if it is *somehow* possible (reverse engineering?!) to change the `Typeface` of the map's labels? The reason is that - as always - the UI designers want that their application-specific font is used everywhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, because the actual rendering is being done in another process, not yours.

Comment: Out of interest: in which one?

Comment: @tommyd: The one for the Play Services Framework, a separate application. All of your calls to `GoogleMap` result in IPC over to the Play Services Framework, return results that are drawn as bitmaps into a `SurfaceView` that is the actual map. Tiles, markers, overlays, etc. are all processed by the Play Services Framework, not by your own app.